# How to display two TextView one(key) by one(value) in android?

Tags: android, dialog, textview

Can anyone please help me to design two TextViews one by one like question and answer.

Ex: Signal Strength = Excellent. Plese see the attachment Image.

[image: design]

Comment: so what's your problem? seems a simple linearlayout will do

Comment: @rupps is that are normal textviews?

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html

```
<LinearLayout
   android:width="match_parent"
   android:height="wrap_content"
   android:orientation="vertical">

   <TextView
       android:width="match_parent"
       android:height="wrap_content"
       android:text="signal strength"/>

   <TextView
       android:width="match_parent"
       android:height="wrap_content"
       android:text="Excellent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use 2 `TextView` object in xml and style them according to your design. You can use `android:textStyle` and `android:textSize` attributes to style TextViews.

Then you **will need to call** `setText()` method in respective `dialog` class to show the results in `value` TextView. For instance:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/keyTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:text="Signal Strength"
    android:textSize="15sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/valueTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/keyTextView"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:text="Excellent"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `TextInputLayout`

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText 
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Excellent"
            android:inputType="none"
            android:hint="Signal Strength" />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

I think it will help you...

let me know if any query

Happy Coding.

Comment: Thanks, But I asked to display that combined TextView only.

Comment: @reegan29 it's in single TextView where one text is a hint and another is as text.